# É correto dizer que vai "treinar" quando na verdade vai "malhar"?

Tags: significado, etimologia

De um tempo para cá estou vendo o uso massivo da palavra “treino” ou “treinamento” substituindo a palavra “malhação” ou “musculação”.

Exemplo:

> Meus treinos são realizados à noite.

Afinal, qual a origem e significado da palavra “treinamento”? Musculação e malhação é um treinamento?

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas devo dizer que qualquer coisa aonde você aprimora algo é um treinamento, independente de ser algo físico ou lógico. Musculação ou malhação são treinos específicos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tá arisco, garoto? :P

Comment: @Math To sim kkkk, vai que me interpretam mal melhor previnir :)

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no título para que ficasse mais focada, se achar errado pode alterar... mas o primeiro titulo me parecia baseado em opnião

Comment: @LucasMotta Achei a edição boa, não porque o titulo anterior parecia opinião, mas por que realmente estava desfocado e você resumiu ao "problema", muito bom :)

Comment: LOL total, a categoria desta pergunta não é *"first world problems"*, mas precisamos de algo parecido pra poder descrever isto :P Sério mesmo, nos anos 90 não existia "malhar", pelo menos não como palavra do dia a dia, nem muito menos substituto pro clássico "treinar"! / cc @Math

Comment: Orion, no offence meant at all, great question! ...... {{comentário candidato a delete}}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Qualquer **ação** que você faz para aprimorar algo é um **treinamento**, independente de ser algo físico ou lógico. *Musculação* ou malhação são treinos *específicos*.

Pra "fazer musculação" ou "malhação" é necessário praticar e como é definido treino é uma prática.

> Note que *malhar* e *malhação* são termos informais, portanto **não** são os termos mais corretos.

## [treinar (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/treinar)

(do francês traîner, arrastar)

1. Dar cevo a (aves). = cevar
   verbo transitivo, intransitivo e pronominal
2. Ensinar ou aprender determinada ação ou prática. = adestrar, **acostumar**
3. Preparar ou **preparar-se** para uma prova, uma competição ou uma atividade.

## [praticar (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/praticar)

1. Pôr em prática, levar a efeito. = cometer, executar, fazer, realizar
2. Exercer uma profissão.
3. Executar regularmente. = **exercitar**
4. Ter por *hábito*, *repetir a mesma operação*.
   verbo intransitivo
5. Conversar, falar.
6. Ter relações ou trato com alguém.

## [musculação (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/muscula%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

*[Desporto]* Conjunto de **exercícios** que visam o fortalecimento e o crescimento dos músculos.

### Conclusão

Para fazer musculação ou malhação (tanto emagrecer quanto fortalecer), é necessário *exercitar*, não é possível fazer treinos avançados sem praticar os básicos e ir evoluindo, portanto é necessário treinar os movimentos e sequências corretas para habituar o corpo a estas atividades.

Vendo na descrição que *treinar* é igual a *acostumar*, e que praticar é igual a *exercitar*, então sim a musculação e malhação são treinos, pois não é possível fazer os exercícios corretamente sem aprendê-los primeiro e também não é possível evoluir para um treino mais aprimorado sem passar pelos treinos mais simples.

Talvez os melhores termos sejam *exercitar*, *praticar academia* e *praticar aeróbica*.

É provável que o termo **treinar** se refira a **treinar o corpo**

Pode parecer que você não aprende nada na academia, mas você ensina o "seu corpo", as células têm memoria também, você habitua o seu corpo com a prática do exercício, para habituar é necessário treiná-lo.

Comment: Ainda estou tentando absorver essa ideia porque sempre vi treinamento como algo ligado ao aprendizado, aprimoramento para competição. Agora a pessoa que quer perder peso ou ganhar massa muscular dizer que vai "treinar" me soa estranho.

Comment: @Orion pode até parecer que você não aprende nada na academia, mas você ensina o "seu corpo", as celulas tem memoria também, você habitua o seu corpo com a pratica do exercício, para habituar é necessário treina-lo :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento As células não tem memória. Quanto à "memória muscular", isso é tanto treino quanto calejar os ossos com lutas, é resistência resultante de lesões apenas, não treinamento. Com relação a treinar, a menos que o esteja fazendo para um fim específico, como uma maratona ou competição de levantamento de peso, sentir dor para se fortalecer e tonificar músculos não configura treinamento. Pois, em relação ao Priberam: 1- o aprendizado é a própria prática da musculação em si, já que quando o corpo se acostuma com um exercício, ele deve ser substituído; e 2 - já foi explicado.

Comment: Conheço treinar e nao malhar

Comment: Caro @ClMend existe mais de um país que usa o idioma português, e girias surgem e até muitas palavras acabam se tornando algum neologismo, claro que no caso desta palavra ela é usada de diferentes formas, como comentei para o Jorge, acho que todos comentários e postagens aqui se ler com calma vai entender que não é algo de todas regiões.

Answer (score 6):

E mais outra adenda. [*Malhar* (Aulete 5)](http://www.aulete.com.br/malhar)  adquiriu provavelmente os seu significado de *praticar musculação* do significado anterior *bater, dar pancada* [(Aulete 1 e 2)](http://www.aulete.com.br/malhar), que por sua vez vem de bater com um [*malho* (Priberam 1, 2 e 4)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/malho). Um *malho* pode ser um grande martelo de ferreiro (daí as expressões *malhar em ferro frio* e *malhar o ferro enquanto está quente*), um maço de calceteiro, ou um instrumento, também conhecido por *mangual*, formado por dois paus ligado por uma correia usados para malhar no trigo, feijão, etc. para separar os bagos da palha. 
[image]

É mais uma coisa do passado, mas ainda há quem use atualmente, como [neste vídeo, onde é usado para debulhar feijão e «perder a pança»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1UmkhjKnQE); Neste [outro temos uma debulha do trigo mais tradicional.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58FWAPWixro)

Comment: Eu dava mais uma adenda, mas é só para dizer que a primeira vez que ouvi a palavra *malhar* nesse sentido foi na novela brasileira **Malhação**.

Comment: @JorgeB. Provavlemente porque estás em Portugal e esse sentido da palavra veio do Brasil. Imagino que a novela se chamou *Malhação*, porque a palavra já era usada antes no Brasil nesse sentido.

Comment: @JorgeB. acredito que a novela é quem popularizou a palavra no Brasil também, claro que talvez ela fosse usada antes em raras situações. Todavia o termo é informal e geralmente é usado para outras situações, como zombar de alguém (raramente) ou pegar no pé de alguém pelo que fez (também informal). Agora situação que vejo muito a palavra *malhar* ser usada no Brasil, é quando algo quebra, tipo o celular cair no chão e quebrar costumamos falar que *malhamos o celular*, em momentos de estresse *vou malhar esse celular na parede* (força de expressão)

Answer (score 5):

Como adenda à resposta existente, note-se que em Portugal a pergunta seria feita ao contrário: a expressão normalmente usada é treinar ou praticar musculação, com as variantes "puxar ferro" e "malhar"; e o substantivo "malhação" nunca é cá usado, embora o percebamos.

Sendo que treinar tem um âmbito *muito* mais alargado, e pode ser usado no contexto de atividades tão diversas como musculação, aikido, futebol, tiro-ao-alvo, natação, canto, xadrez, DotA... :)

Comment: Usamos no Brasil também "puxar ferro" e "malhar" e também usamos treinar para outros esportes.

Answer (score -2):

Treino é uma preparação para  futura competição  ;)

Comment: Sugiro uma lida no https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/conduct antes de comecar a responder.

Comment: @AFetter , não percebo; que parte desta resposta te parece não seguir o Code of Conduct? Parece-me uma resposta amigável e perfeitamente respeitosa.