# Donde vem a expressão "sem eira nem beira"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

[***Sem eira nem beira*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/eira) significa muito pobre. A ***eira*** compreende-se bem. A *eira* é um pedaço de chão plano e duro onde, em tempos, os agricultores punham os cereais ou leguminosas a secar ao sol, e depois os malhavam [(ergunta acerca de mlhar)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/597/%C3%89-correto-dizer-que-vai-treinar-quando-na-verdade-vai-malhar) para separar a semente da palha. Portanto compreende-se que eira fosse sinónimo de abundância. Mas a ***beira***? Que significa não ter ***beira***?

A expressão já vem de longe. Encontramo-la em 1526 neste diálogo entre Duarte e Almeida na farsa [*O Clérigo da Beira*](http://ww3.fl.ul.pt/centros_invst/teatro/pagina/Publicacoes/Pecas/Textos_GV/clerigo_da_beira.pdf) de [Gil Vicente](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gil_Vicente):

[image]
Gil Vicente, *Clérigo da Beira*, [edição de 1562](http://purl.pt/252/3/#/490) (a primeira é de 1526) e [edição mais legível de 1834.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9K1dAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA254&dq=%22nem%20tenho%20eira%20nem%20beira%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXgfC_97LSAhXH0xQKHQvhDUsQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=%22nem%20tenho%20eira%20nem%20beira%22&f=false)

Comment: Eu não tenho essa interpretação de eira. Acho que é mais: não tem sequer uma eira (nem sequer tem um pedaço de chão).

Comment: Uma pessoa podia ter terreno e não ter eira: podia usar a eira doutra pessoa; nalgumas zonas havia também eiras comunitárias. É  a ideia que dá este artigo sobre o [ciclo do pão na Bismula](https://capeiaarraiana.wordpress.com/2012/04/). A eira não podia ser cultivada, algumas até eram empedradas. Seria um desperdício cada família ter uma eira que depois só seria usada meia dúzia de dias por ano. [Outro artigo sobre trabalho na eira](http://opombalinho.blogspot.pt/2008/10/quinta-ferno-leite-em-194045.html). Daí a minha ideia de a *eira* poder ser metáfora para o produto que de lá vinha.

Comment: Usamos a expressão no Brasil, mas ela certamente teve origem em Portugal.  Digo isso porque não usamos os substantivos "eira" e "beira" separadamente, apenas na expressão.  Usamos "a beira de", "na beira de", "na beirada de", mas não "uma beira" ou "uma eira", ao contrário do que ocorre em Terras Lusitanas.

Comment: @Centaurus, A *eira* pertence à agricultura manual do passado. Mas o Aulete tem até um significado especificamente brasileiro. Agora a expressão já era usada em 1526. Em Portugal *beira* também é sempre beira de alguma coisa, estrada, rio, etc.. E "querer sol na eira e chuva no nabal" não conheces?

Comment: "querer sol na eira e chuva no nabal"   Não, nunca ouvi. O que significa?  Imagino que as duas coisas sejam boas para o agricultor e que o ditado signifique "querer demais", ou "só querer aquilo que serve".  É isso ?

Comment: Sim, significa querer que tudo seja sempre como convém, para além do razoável.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estive a fazer uma breve pesquisa e encontrei uma [abordagem interessante](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/proverbios/) sobre beira:

> Beira é a beirada da eira. Quando uma eira não tem beira, o vento leva
>   os grãos e o proprietário fica sem nada. Na região nordeste este
>   ditado tem o mesmo significado mas outra explicação. Dizem que
>   antigamente as casas das pessoas ricas tinham um telhado triplo: a
>   eira, a beira e a tribeira como era chamada a parte mais alta do
>   telhado. As pessoas mais pobres não tinham condições de fazer este
>   telhado , então construíam somente a tribeira ficando assim "sem eira
>   nem beira".

[Outra abordagem](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/sem+eira+nem+beira/) que encontrei foi:

> Expressão popular que significa : não possuir coisa alguma; ser
>   extremamente pobre.Tem origem portuguesa; eira era o quintal,espaço
>   livre; beira era o beiral da casa. Portanto quem não tem nem eira nem
>   beira ,não tem nem terra nem casa.

Depois de ler estas duas explicações parece-me que o mais obvio será uma pessoa que não tem nem terreno (eira) nem casa (beira).

Comment: Bom trabalho de investigação. Mas essa do vento levar o grão é treta. Eu trabalhei em eiras. Depois de se ter tirado a palha grossa, e restar na eira uma mistura de palha fina e grão (trigo, feijão, grão de bico, o que for), atira-se a mistura ao ar com uma pá para o vento levar a palha; o grão é mas pesado e cai de novo na eira.

Comment: É essa também não me pareceu nada. Eu cresci numa aldeia também. Mas *não tens eira nem beira* pode muito bem ter vindo de não tens terra nem tecto. Seria uma boa analogia.

Comment: Bem interessante.  +1