# Quando é que «malhar» começou a ser usado no sentido de ‘fazer exercícios de musculação’?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, origem-histórica

Procure-se ***malhar*** no Google, e praticamente todos os resultados têm a ver com musculação. [Uma imagem do Google images vale por mil palavras:](https://www.google.pt/search?q=malhar&num=50&lr=lang_pt&hl=en&as_qdr=all&tbs=lr:lang_1pt&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTkZj6kOnOAhWGXBQKHZcBBj8QsAQIHA)
[image: diversas imagens referentes a malhar, todas acerca de exercício físico]

Mas esta é apenas uma das nove aceções de [*malhar* apresentadas no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/malhar), contando apenas as derivadas de [*malho* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/malho); (exemplos omitidos):

> 1. Bater com malho, martelo ou instrumento similar
> 2. Espancar, dar pancada em
> 3. Fig. Falar mal de; criticar severamente
> 4. P.ext. Zombar, escarnecer de
> 5. Bras. Pop. Fazer exercícios físicos para fortalecer a musculatura
> 6. Bras. Gír. Entre os traficantes, aumentar a quantidade de (drogas tóxicas) acrescentando outras substâncias
> 7. Bras. Pop. Soltar a voz (sapo); COAXAR
> 8. Fig. Cair, despenhar-se
> 9. Debulhar (cereais) utilizando o mangual

Já existe [esta pergunta sobre se é correto dizer-se *treinar* neste sentido de *malhar*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/597/%C3%89-correto-dizer-que-vai-treinar-quando-na-verdade-vai-malhar). A minha questão aqui é:

- **Quando é que *malhar* passou a ser usado com o sentido de fazer exercícios de musculação?**
- **Quais eram os termos usados anteriormente?**

Comment: Tenho a certeza de que nunca ouvi "malhar" nesse sentido antes de 1980.  E tenho a certeza de que já ouvia por volta de 1995. Antes do aparecimento dos grandes aparelhos de musculação, trabalhava-se os músculos com halteres e praticava-se halterofilismo com o objetivo de provocar hipertrofia muscular.  Posto apenas como comentário uma vez que não fiz nenhuma pesquisa a respeito.

Comment: @Centaurus há quem diga que tem a ver com o aparecimento da [novela Malhação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malha%C3%A7%C3%A3o) que começou precisamente em 1995.

Comment: @JorgeB.  Pode ser que seja.

Comment: @Jacinto Possible duplicate of [É correto dizer que vai “treinar” quando na verdade vai “malhar”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/597/%c3%89-correto-dizer-que-vai-treinar-quando-na-verdade-vai-malhar)

Comment: @José A pergunta que referes é na verdade sobre o significado e origem de *treinar*. É verdade que a minha resposta lá já avança com a possível origem de *malhar* neste sentido, mas ainda assim não responde às perguntas que eu faço aqui.

Comment: @Jacinto The banner at the top of the question "This question may already have an answer" is only visible to you (and allows you to close your own question as a duplicate, which is sometimes useful, even if not with this particular question). I expect the banner will eventually expire, once the close votes or close flags expire (although I can't see any active close votes/flags). See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167980/299332

Comment: @Earthliŋ Ok. I was wondering why I had never seen such a banner.

Comment: @JorgeB. vê a resposta do Geraldo: já existia em 1983.

Comment: @Jacinto cai por terra a minha teoria :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem antes da novela Malhação, por volta de 1984, tinha um quadro no "Viva Gordo" com várias pessoas fazendo ginástica e eles usavam o bordão "Vamos Malhar, gente!", com o duplo sentido (fazer ginástica e falar mal dos outros). Em 1983, Marcos Valle lançou a música [“Estrelar” (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTPaDbt_USA) alusiva à boa forma, à prática de exercícios físicos, que falava "tem que malhar, tem que suar...".

Comment: Excelente, obrigado pela contribuição. lncluí o link à canção na tua resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que é impossível definir ao certo quando, mas lê [SIGNIFICADOS PROVENIENTES DE GÍRIAS EM LÍNGUA PORTUGUESA – UM ESTUDO DE CINCO CASOS](http://www.pgletras.uerj.br/palimpsesto/num21/estudos/Palimpsesto21estudos07.pdf).

> nota‐se  que  os  significados  buscados — *AKA malhar* —  foram  legitimados  pelos dicionários no início do século XXI.
>
> **malhar**: na edição de 1925 a palavra possui três entradas. Na primeira, a acepção primária é: “bater em malho, martelo ou outro instrumento análogo: malhar o trigo”. Na segunda entrada trata-se de um verbo intransitivo, “cahir na malha ou na rede” e na terceira entrada, significa “reunir (gado) em certo ponto”.
>
> A acepção da pesquisa é encontrada na edição de 2011, marcada como “Bras. Pop.”, que quer dizer que se trata de um brasileirismo popular; é a quinta da primeira entrada do verbo: “fazer exercícios físicos para fortalecer a musculatura” e o dicionário apresenta dois exemplos de uso: “No ginásio, malhava todo o corpo” e “o halterofilista costumava malhar de manhã”.

Ou seja, em 2011 a palavra malhar foi aceita pelos dicionários. Claro que podes dizer que ela já era usada antes, mas a partir deste momento ela passa a ser oficial logo começa a ser usada oficialmente.

Ainda seguindo o texto:

> a) malhação: a acepção primária da edição de 2001 é “ato ou efeito de malhar; malha,  malhada”. .

Ou seja, em 2001 ela aparece já nos dicionários classificada como gíria.

Como a [Novela Malhação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malha%C3%A7%C3%A3o) vai ao ar em 1995, a primeira aparição num dicionário foi em 2001 e o artigo não encontrou nada nas edicições dos dicionários de 1986, creio que a data de aparição deve ter sido entre 1986 e 1995 mas, como já disse, não sei se é possível assim sem um estudo mais profundo dar uma data mais específica.

Comment: Bem, se não vem no dicionário de 1986, a origem não deverá ser muito anterior a esse ano; nós já sabíamos que não era posterior a 1995. Podes procura no Google Books, se quiseres incluir na resposta o exemplo mais antigo que for possível encontrar.

Comment: Encontrei uma ocorrência numa [*Manchete* de 1987](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22al%C3%A9m+de+malhar+0+atleta%22&oq=%22al%C3%A9m+de+malhar+0+atleta%22&gs_l=serp.3...16564.17102.0.17891.2.2.0.0.0.0.96.164.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.c1naaAbSKpQ): "Além de **malhar** o atleta do fisioculturismo precisa se alimentar bem [...] **Malho** há apenas cinco meses [...]"

Answer (score 0):

Sou professor de Educação Física e me explicaram que a palavra vem da "malha" (tecido) que as pessoas usavam para fazer exercício! Desde quando? sei lá! Na Roma antiga, ainda antes de Cristo, os soldados (que obviamente se exercitavam bastante lutando, marchando, treinando...) já vestiam uma roupa chamada de "cota de malha" feita de pequenas pecinhas de metal unidas para se proteger, minimizar ataques de espadas, lanças, flechas...essa roupa  foi usada até muitos anos depois tendo seu uso consagrado pelos cavaleiros medievais! Como até então exercício era coisa de "militar" , creio mesmo que a palavra tenha uma origem relacionada a isso...Na musculação até hoje há o termo "MAROMBEIRO" para o praticante, e minha mãe (nascida em 1934) usava o termo "MAROMBAR"! ("vai marombar hoje, filhinho?" dizia quando me via sair para a academia...