# Qual é a origem da palavra «zoeira»?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro

Como se pode ver no dicionário Priberam zoeira pode ser um vento forte, mas ultimamente, e pelo menos no Brasil, é usado como "fazer troça" de alguém ou alguma coisa.

Mas afinal qual é a origem da palavra com esse significado?

> zo·ei·ra (zoar + -eira) substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Ruído confuso ou constante (ex.: saí do concerto com uma zoeira na cabeça). = ZOADA
> 2. Ruído semelhante ao que fazem alguns insectos (ex.: não se assuste se sentir uma zoeira nos ouvidos). = ZOADA, ZUMBIDO
> 3. [Portugal: Minho]  Vento forte.
> 4. [Regionalismo]  Valentia, coragem.
> 5. [Brasil, Informal]  Confusão, conflito, escândalo ou gritaria (ex.: eles arrumavam muita zoeira na escola).
> 6. **[Brasil, Informal]  Comentário ou brincadeira trocista (ex.: o entrevistador foi alvo de zoeira). substantivo de dois géneros**
> 7. [Portugal, Informal]  Pessoa leviana ou aparvalhada.
>
> "zoeira", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, http://priberam.pt/dlpo/zoeira [consultado em 21-11-2016].

Comment: Zoeira com esse sentido de criar uma confusão, como a própria pergunta sugere. Hoje chamam de trolagem por causa dos Trolls.

Comment: "zoar" e "zoeira" são gírias relativamente recentes.  E quando digo recentes, quero dizer inexistentes no início dos anos 90.  É melhor explicar antes que alguém com 25 anos de idade venha dizer que são muito antigas.

Comment: @Centaurus também tinha essa ideia.

Comment: Zoeira assim com zombar seriam de origem africana.

Comment: @Centaurus [este livro](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nsBbAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA127&dq=%22zoeira%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwics9CkisHQAhUFJsAKHVkOCwI43AEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22zoeira%22&f=false) mostra que a palavra data pelo menos de 1858

Comment: @BrunoCosta mas essa eu sei, mas quando é que começou a ser usada para o ponto 6? E porquê?

Comment: @AndréLyra *Zoar, zombar* e *zombaria* já estavam em uso no século XV (Houaiss), o que torna a origem africana improvável. Alguns etimólogos sugerem origem onomatopaica , juntamente com *zumbir*.

Comment: Quem diz são alguns sites como esse [Palavras de origem africana no vocabulário brasileiro](http://raizdosambaemfoco.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/palavras-de-origem-africana-no-vocabulario-brasileiro/) @Jacinto

Comment: @BrunoCosta  E o que tem o livro a ver com as gírias "zoar" e "zoeira"?  Não encontrei nenhuma gíria por lá.

Comment: @AndréLyra Interessante, o site. Mas obviamente algumas das fontes lá usadas não são muito fiáveis. Eu encontrei a *zombaria* do século XV. Foi o rei D. Duarte que escreveu no *Leal Conselheiro* em 1438. Isto foi uns seis anos antes dos portugueses chegarem à Guiné. Podes ver [aqui](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/) (registo necessário, mas gratuito): "Pois estas cousas taaes esguardará o albardam [*aldrabão*?] na zombaria, e nom as veerá o homem sabedor em sua vyda?"

Comment: @JorgeB., eu me lembro que quando era bem novo não se usava "zoeira" (~1999), o que era muito usado na época era "avacalhação" e "avacalhar". Na minha região (SC), "zoeira" começou a ser usada só depois dos anos 2000. Acho que começou em SP, lembro bem do o pessoal que falava, escutavam muita música da região e tinham até um pouco de sotaque paulista, mesmo sendo residentes de Florianópolis. Meu chute é que foi usada fora de contexto, por pessoas que não sabiam o real significado mas que devido à sonoridade da palavra pareceu encaixar, aí espalhou-se feito erava daininha! `:D`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos muito interessante e vem confirmar o Centaurus. Era bom descobrir como realmente aconteceu...

Comment: @JorgeB., sendo o Brasil a imensidão que é somado ao fato da gíria ter surgido num contexto onde a globalização estava entrando em cena (fortemente) acho bastante difícil (para não dizer impossível) descobrir a origem da coisa. Com precisão ao menos, imprecisamente eu diria que veio de SP, a chance é grande! E sim, o Centaurus tem toda a razão, embora acho que ele errou em dizer "25 anos", visto que nós vimos a gíria entrar em cena `;D`.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos mas deve haver alguma explicação de como é que apareceu, tipo como é que apareceu malhação, acha-se que foi na mesma altura da novela.

Comment: Jorge, e tu a dares-lhe com a novela. *Malhar* já aparecia na revista Manchete em 1987, nove anos antes da novela. Vê comentário à [resposta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3607/quando-%C3%A9-que-malhar-come%C3%A7ou-a-ser-usado-no-sentido-de-fazer-exerc%C3%ADcios-de-mus).

Comment: @Jacinto tens razão, mas a malhação no minimo será a impulsionadora do uso, digo eu claro.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, eu tenho 26 anos, e, na minha adolescência, já usávamos termos como `estou te zoando` ou `estão de zoação com a sua cara`. O termo `zoeira` mesmo teve seu uso difundido através da internet, em *chans* da vida, possivelmente como uma adaptação do termo `trolling`, em inglês.

Comment: Acredito que zueira/zoeira/zoueira venha de zoação que vem de zoar que vem de zoada. Zoada por sua vez não é um termo novo e desde criança (mas de 30 anos atrás) ouço como termo comum para "barulho muito alto" geralmente associada com baderna

Comment: @jean Essas palavras são muito antigas. O dicionário Houaiss indica a existência de *zoar* no século XV; de *zoada* em 1772; e de *zoeira* em 1899; não tinham ainda na altura, que nós saibamos, era os significados associados a 'zombar, troçar'. E é isso que a pergunta pede, como surgiram esses significados.

Answer (score -1):

Aqui em Salvador, Bahia, nós usamos *zuada*  ao inves de barulho portanto esse termo é bem antigo, e tambem usavamos *azuando* e *zuação* desde os anos 70.